# send 2 different emails when laravel event triggered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-events

I want to have 2 notifications when new user registered:

1. inform admin that we have new user for moderation
2. send welcome email to new user

I created 2 events, put them in EventServiceProvider, but as result I have 2 emails to admin. I already tried to register 4 users with different emails, but none of them receive welcome email. It is always sent to admin `config('mail.to.address')`
For some reason welcome email sent to admin, instead of new user. What's wrong?
My code is below.

EventServiceProvider

```
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
            SendWelcomeEmail::class,
            SendNewUserRegisteredEmail::class,
        ],
    ];
```

SendWelcomeEmail

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Mail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class SendWelcomeEmail
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $event->user->name, 
            'email' => $event->user->email
        );
 
        Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to($data['email'])
                    ->subject('Добро пожаловать на сайт '.config('app.name'). '.');
            $message->from(config('mail.from.address'));
        });
    }
}
```

SendNewUserRegisteredEmail

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Mail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class SendNewUserRegisteredEmail
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $event->user->name, 
            'email' => $event->user->email
        );
 
        Mail::send('emails.registered', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to(config('mail.to.address'))
                    ->subject('Новый пользователь на сайте '.config('app.name'). '.');
            $message->from(config('mail.from.address'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where your dispatching event ? add that code

Comment: I don't have additional code. I just found that in standard controller `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController` already exists piece of code `event(new Registered($user));`.

Comment: Then I decided to add 2 more classes listening this event  in EventServiceProvider